# Creating rain using canvas. I can create an individual droplet that falls or random drops across the top but I how do I combine these two effects?

Tags: javascript, oop, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a rain effect using canvas. Within the code I have added comments "POINT 1", "POINT 2" and "POINT 3" to help you understand what part I'm talking about.

- "POINT 1" creates multiple droplets with a random x-axis and a y-axis of 0.
- "POINT 3" (commented out) creates a single droplet which correctly increases the y-axis so that the droplet falls.

I need "POINT 3" to be applied to every droplet that is create in "POINT 1". "POINT 2" is part of my attempt to do this but instead it creates a new droplet that is lower rather than lowering the droplet that was previously created.

Any help is very much appreciated,

Steve.

I have create a JS Fiddle for this here: https://jsfiddle.net/xrainbowuk/qaws59uz/10/

```js
/* ///// ///// ///// ///// */

var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
var canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

//RAIN DROP CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION
function Rain(rainDropStandardX, rainDropStandardY, opacity) {
    this.rainDropStandardX = rainDropStandardX;
    this.rainDropStandardY = rainDropStandardY;
    this.opacity = opacity;
    
    var dropTipX = rainDropStandardX + 0;
    var dropTipY = rainDropStandardY + 0;
    var dropBottomLeftX = rainDropStandardX - 15;
    var dropBottomLeftY = rainDropStandardY + 40;
    var dropBottomRightX = rainDropStandardX + 15;
    var dropBottomRightY = rainDropStandardY + 40;
    
    this.droplet = function() {
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(dropTipX, dropTipY); // line on the right 
        c.bezierCurveTo(dropBottomLeftX, dropBottomLeftY, dropBottomRightX, dropBottomRightY, dropTipX, dropTipY);
        c.fillStyle = "rgba(43, 173, 255, " + this.opacity + ")";
        c.fill();
    }
}

/* POINT 1 - This piece of code produces multiple droplets but their "y-axis" value never increases */
var rngPosY = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    var rngPosX = Math.random() * canvasWidth;
    var rngOpacity = Math.random() * (1 - 0.1) + 0.1;
    
    var rainDrop = new Rain(rngPosX, rngPosY, rngOpacity);
    rainDrop.droplet();
    //rngPosY += 10; /* POINT 2 - This will make the next droplet lower (increase y-axis). Not lower the individual droplets */
}, 500);

/* POINT 3 - A single droplet is created and then the "y-axis" value increases */
/*
var rngPosY = 0;
var rngPosX = Math.random() * canvasWidth;
var rngOpacity = Math.random() * (1 - 0.1) + 0.1;

setInterval(function() {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    var rainDrop = new Rain(rngPosX, rngPosY, rngOpacity);
    rainDrop.droplet();
    rngPosY += 5;
}, 1);
*/
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

canvas {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas Rain</title>
    <link href="css/RG5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas>
     Your browser does not support HTML canvas.
    </canvas>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <script src="js/RG5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an array where to save your drops. In my code this array is: `var rain`. Also you will need a method to update every drop.

Another important think is a way to remove drops from the array if the y position is > canvasHeight.

```js
if (d.rainDropStandardY > canvasHeight) {
      rain.splice(i, 1);
    }
```

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth);
var canvasHeight = (canvas.height = window.innerHeight);
// an array where to save the drops of rain
var rain = [];

//RAIN DROP CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION
function Rain(rainDropStandardX, rainDropStandardY, opacity) {
  this.rainDropStandardX = rainDropStandardX;
  this.rainDropStandardY = rainDropStandardY;
  this.opacity = opacity;
  // the speed of the drop: a different one for every drop
  this.v = {
    x: .5 + Math.random(),
    y: .5 + Math.random() * 10
  };
  //console.log(this.v)

  this.droplet = function() {
    var dropTipX = this.rainDropStandardX + 0;
    var dropTipY = this.rainDropStandardY + 0;
    var dropBottomLeftX = this.rainDropStandardX - 15;
    var dropBottomLeftY = this.rainDropStandardY + 40;
    var dropBottomRightX = this.rainDropStandardX + 15;
    var dropBottomRightY = this.rainDropStandardY + 40;

    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(dropTipX, dropTipY); // line on the right
    c.bezierCurveTo(
      dropBottomLeftX,
      dropBottomLeftY,
      dropBottomRightX,
      dropBottomRightY,
      dropTipX,
      dropTipY
    );
    c.fillStyle = "rgba(43, 173, 255, " + this.opacity + ")";
    c.fill();
  };


// a method to update the position of the drop
  this.update = function() {
    this.rainDropStandardX += this.v.x;
    this.rainDropStandardY += this.v.y;

    this.droplet();
  };
}

/* This piece of code produces multiple droplets but their "y-axis" value never increases */
var rngPosY = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  var rngPosX = Math.random() * canvasWidth;
  var rngOpacity = Math.random() * (1 - 0.1) + 0.1;
  // you create a new drop and push it in the array
  rain.push(new Rain(rngPosX, rngPosY, rngOpacity));

  //rngPosY += 10; /*This will make the next droplet lower (increase y-axis). Not lower the individual droplets */
}, 500);

function frame() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  // for every drop in the array
  rain.forEach((d, i) => {
    //you update the position and redraw the drop
    d.update();
    // if the trop is out of the canvas you remove the drop from the array
    if (d.rainDropStandardY > canvasHeight) {
      rain.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
}
frame();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

canvas {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas>Your browser does not support HTML canvas.
    </canvas>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: enxaneta, thank you very much. That's really helpful. It works perfectly but there is one part I don't quite understand. What is the purpose of "d", which first occurs within the "forEach"? I understand it is a condition within the arrow function but otherwise I don't know what it's purpose is.

Comment: Here `d` stands for drop and `rain` is the array of all drops. For each **d**rop in the array, `update` the position of the drop and draw it again. Then if the **d**rop is out of the canvas you remove the drop from the array.  If you prefer you can use a for loop here: `for(let i = 0; i < rain.length; i++){rain[i].update()...`. In this case `rain[i]`would be the same as the `d` in the `forEach`

Comment: Ah ok. I understand. One final thing, if I leave the page open but I am using a different tab in the browser, a different application, etc. "setInterval" keeps adding to the array so that when I move back to the page (not reload the page) all of those droplets appear at the same time with the same y-axis value. I've tried adding an "if" statement within the "setInterval" code but then creates waves of droplets rather than a smooth flow. I tried adding the "setInterval" content to the "frame" function but that fills up the array too quickly. Any ideas?

Comment: You can move the functionality you have now in the frame function. However, since `requestAnimationFrame` fires 60 times every second and you need to generate those drops not that often, you may need to declare a global `var frames = 0`. Then inside the function frame() you may do `frames++`. Then if frames%10 == 0 you create a new drop. Another way would be using the [timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) indicating the point in time when requestAnimationFrame() starts to execute callback functions.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I'll have to look into timestamp because that's not something I've come across before. Much appreciated, man!